# How do I define the spec of an elixir function that has an unused parameters?

Tags: elixir

```
@spec another(String.t, String.t) :: String.t 
def another(_para1, _para2) do
  IO.puts "this is a test"
end
```

can i define the type of the parameters of the function this way even though the parameters are not used in the body of the function?

Comment: Yes, does it not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it and it's syntactically valid. The `@spec` attribute should contain all of the expected inputs and outputs gathered in one place. In this case you're saying to the `dialyzer` (and implicitly to the code's reader) that this function will accept only strings.

Question is why you want to do that? If you don't need these parameters why do you want to accept them? If it's your last clause, everything is ok, because you have other definitions for that function and they accept only strings, so `@spec` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow any arguments, you could use type `any()` in you definition

```
@spec another(any(), any()) :: String.t
```